# PDO Memory Leak

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My current code looks like:

```
$key = sha1(microtime().rand().microtime().rand()); // not used for security threads
try {
    $s = \DB::_('my-cms')->prepare('INSERT INTO keys (user_name, user_email, key) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
    $s->execute([$name, $email, $key]);
    return $key;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    die(print_r($e));
}
```

When executing this code, I always get a PHP Fatal Error `Allowed memory size of x bytes exhausted`.

When not using a try-catch model, the Exception
`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;` is thrown.

Although `key` is no reserved MySql keyword, setting the `key` column name in backticks fixes the error.

Nonetheless this should not cause a memory exhaustion! I have not found any similar issues...

Comment: `key` and `keys` are both [mysql reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), so they can't be used as a table or column name without enclosing them in backticks (`\``) in your queries

Comment: @MarkBaker My bad, I looked at the 5.5 reference instead of 5.7

Comment: They were both reserved words in [MySQL 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) as well

Comment: It is likely a memory leak not in PDO but rather in your DB class